# constructors and conversions of classes

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have 2 classes:

```
class iterator {
    Node<K,V>* n;
public:
    iterator(){
        std::cout<<"new empty iterator"<<std::endl;
    };
    iterator(const iterator& iter):n(iter.n){
        std::cout<<"copy iterator"<<std::endl;
    }
    explicit iterator(Node<K,V>* nodePtr):n(nodePtr) {
        std::cout<<"create iterator with Node Ptr"<<std::endl;
    }
    iterator& operator=(const iterator& iter);
    void operator++();
    Node<K,V>& operator*();
    bool operator!=(const iterator& iter);
    K& operator[](const Key& k)const;
    V& operator[](const Val& v)const;
    Node<K,V>* getNodePtr()const{
        std::cout<<"get Node Ptr"<<std::endl;
        return n;
    }
    friend class Map;
};

class const_iterator :public iterator {
    const Node<K,V>* n;
public:
    const_iterator(){
        std::cout<<"new empty const_iterator"<<std::endl;
    };
    const_iterator(const iterator& iter):
        n(iter.getNodePtr()){
        std::cout<<"convert"<<std::endl;
    }
    const_iterator(const const_iterator& iter):n(iter.n){}
    explicit const_iterator(const Node<K,V>* node):n(node){}
    const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator& iter){
        n = iter.n;
        return *this;
    }
    const Node<K,V>& operator*(){
        return *n;
    }
    friend class Map;
};

iterator begin()const{
    return iterator(firstKey);
}
iterator end()const{
    return iterator(dummyKey);
}
```

I want it to make an automatic conversion between the 2 classes using:

```
    const_iterator(const iterator& iter):
        n(iter.getNodePtr()){
        std::cout<<"convert"<<std::endl;
    }
```

to do something like this for example:

```
 Map<int,int>::const_iterator it = m.begin();
```

now, the thing is, that this constructor calls for some reason iterator(); in the first class and I can't figure out why.
I know begin() and end() have some standart versions, but I can't use any of it here. I also can't make Map to be const, or write a conversion function. 
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made `iterator` a base class of `const_iterator`, so an `iterator` constructor will (and should) be called as part of constructing a `const_iterator`.

Comment: that's what I've suspected. is there a way around it other than making them 2 different classes with no inheritence?

Comment: @littlerunaway : If there's a good reason to have an "is-a" relationship (ie. inheritance), then the base class has to be constructed. If there's not a good reason to have an "is-a" relationship, then just drop the inheritance. The latter is probably more appropriate in this case.

Comment: @littlerunaway: currently, `const_iterator` has 2 `Node<K,V>*`, `const_iterator` may use the one in `iterator` (if you keep the inheritance) and so you need to call the correct constructor.

Comment: you actually solved my problem. the iterator constructor is still gets called but now it's one with iter as a parameter so I don't create an empty one. works brilliantly now. thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you will define data storage as

```
const Map<int, int> data;
```

instead of

```
Map<int, int> data;
```

const version of begin() and end() will be invoked.

Also, C++11 standard containers add `cbegin()` and `cend()` for that purpose. You could re-difine it as follows:

```
const_iterator cbegin()const{
    return const_iterator(firstKey);
}
const_iterator cend()const{
    return const_iterator(dummyKey);
}
```

Comment: I've mentioned I can't do this, define Map as const.

Comment: @littlerunaway please check cbegin()/cend() addition

Comment: can't use and standart versions of these functions. mentioned that too